# Converting String To NSDate Returned From Google Always Returns Nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

Converting string to date always returns nil.  Must be missing something here:

```
NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = nil;
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&httpResponse error:nil];
NSString *dateString = [[httpResponse allHeaderFields] objectForKey:@"Date"];
DebugLog(@" *** GOOGLE DATE:  %@ ****",dateString); 


NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"E MMM d yyyy" options:0 locale:locale];
NSDate *currentDateFromWeb = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString];
```

String prints correctly as: `Wed, 28 Jul 2021 13:51:16 GMT`

Tried a variety of date formatter styles, still `nil`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "zzz" for the time-zone:

```
"E, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"
```

So, this should give you a valid date:

```
NSString *str = @"Wed, 28 Jul 2021 13:51:16 GMT";

NSDateFormatter *df = [NSDateFormatter new];
[df setDateFormat:@"E, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"];

NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[df setLocale:locale];

NSDate *d = [df dateFromString:str];

NSLog(@"d: %@", d);
```

Output (where I am, US East Coast):

```
d: Wed Jul 28 09:51:16 2021
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! Tried so many combos for this time zone! Thanks again